# Custom part of speech tagging with fallback to nltk internal pos

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

In my business domain the combination of these 2 words: "**doorman building**" should always be tagged as **(doorman: "JJ") (building: "NN")**.
nltk internal tagger tags it as:

```
nltk.pos_tag(["doorman", "building"]) -> [('doorman', 'NN'), ('building', 'NN')]
```

My approach was to create a **BigramTagger** and to train it with this sentence:

```
train_sents = [
    [('doorman', 'JJ'), ('building', 'NN')]
]
```

and to backoff it with nltk internal tagger for all other cases.

```
default_tagger = nltk.data.load("../nltk_data/taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle")
bigram_tagger = nltk.BigramTagger(train_sents, backoff=default_tagger)
```

However, when i try to use it like this:

```
bigram_tagger.tag(nltk.word_tokenize("Elegant doorman building with gym"))`
```

seems like the BigramTaager was not applied, i get:

```
[('Elegant', 'NNP'), ('doorman', 'NN'), ('building', 'NN'), ('with', 'IN'), ('gym', 'NN')]
```

But this does seem to work:

```
bigram_tagger.tag(nltk.word_tokenize("doorman building")) -> [('doorman', 'JJ'), ('building', 'NN')]
```

obviously i'm missing something in the way i should use theses components,
what would be a good strategy to have the nltk internal pos tagger but also to "override" it in some specific cases related to a specific business domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, grammatically the nltk tagger is correct: "doorman building" is a noun-noun compound. But to answer the technical question, the `BigramTagger` tags one word at a time, based on prior context. Your custom tagger cannot tag "doorman" when it follows "elegant", so it delegates to the default and you end up with `("doorman", "JJ")` before you've gotten to "building".

If you're sure you want to go this route (and my guess is it could do more harm than good), I recommend applying your corrections by post-processing, after the tagger has done its job. Examples like the one you give don't need a full tagger, you can just match the sequence of words and apply substitutions to the tagged version.

Comment: Thanks, it makes perfect sense

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer has resolved your question, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark on the left.